# Display picture in page from different recordset in Dynamics NAV 2009

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I'd like to display a picture, that is saved as a blob, on a page that not binds the record.

I created a field in `Table 79` of type *BLOB* and subtype *BitMap*.
Then I added the field **TestPicture** on `Page 1` to actually insert an image manually. It gets displayed correctly on `Page 1` (since `Page 1` binds `Table 79`)

However, I want to display this picture on `Page 5050` as well, so I added a record of `Table 79`, filtered the record and did `CALCFIELDS`.

```
OnInit():
recCompanyInfo.GET;
recCompanyInfo.CALCFIELDS("TestPicture");
```

I created a new field on `Page 5050` and set the `SourceExpr` to the *BLOB* field **TestPicture** on my added record variable `recCompanyInfo`.

But it does not show the picture, instead it displays a greyed out text field.

What did I do wrong?

#### Edit

Dynamics NAV 2009 SP1, RTC

Comment: At which trigger have you added the code? Probably you should use OnSfterGetRecord.

Comment: @Mark I tried ```OnInit()```, ```OnOpenPage()``` and ```OnAfterGetRecord()```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick solution is create the same field in table **5050 (Contact)** in **OnAfterGetRecord()** trigger put your Code.

```
recCompanyInfo.GET;
recCompanyInfo.CALCFIELDS(TestPicture);
TestPicture = recCompanyInfo.TestPicture;
```

And display in page 5050 the Field TestPicture of the **Contact Table**.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, does it store the assigned in the database?

Comment: Ok, it does store it in the database, i will put a clear on the OnModify,OnInsert trigger of the table then.

Comment: Perfect, The assignment is only in memory to show the value in page but if you make any changes on page save the value. If you do not want to save the value in fields **TestPicture** put this code in trigger **OnModifyRecord()**

    CLEAR(TestPicture);

Comment: Yes, I made sure to ```CLEAR``` the display only _BLOBs_ at ```OnModify```and ```OnInsert```